# How to implement proxy settings in Service Reference?

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services

i have a proxy internet connection.
in my windows application i was added web service as a **service reference** (.asmx).

now i want to access the service reference methods using proxy connection.

but for me through proxy connection i couldn't access my service reference.

need ur suggestions with examples.

note:
normally if we add the web service as a web refernce then it is working but the web service will work if i added as a service reference

regards
anbu

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the proxy in code before you use the reference:

```
MyWebService.Name service = new MyWebService.Name();
System.Net.WebProxy proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy("10.1.2.3", 8080); //use your proxy here

proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
service.Proxy = proxy;
```

Then make your service calls as normal:

```
service.DoSomething();
```